# Unity Touch position not working

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have some issues with my Android/iOS game.
The concept is pretty simple (Portrait mode) : 
If you tap on the left part of the screen, it bumps the ball to the right. 
If you tap on the right part of the screen, it bumps the ball to the left.

The problem is, I've put this code in my controller script :

```
void TouchManagement()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< Input.touchCount; ++i)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
            if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Debug.Log(touch.position);
                if(touch.position.x > Screen.width/2f && timer == 0f)
                {
                    BumpLeft();
                }
                else if (touch.position.x <= Screen.width / 2f && timer == 0f)
                {
                    BumpRight();
                }
                timer = cooldown;
            }
        }
    }
```

And no matter where I tap when playing my build on my phone, the ball goes to the right. I can't even debug.log touch position with Unity remote since my phone isn't recognized for some reason.

According to other forum posts and questions, this code should work (And works with other inputs in the Editor), so I've no idea what to do.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe the timer is not exactly 0.0f? Comparing floats with equal is always tricky. If Debug.Log(...) is not working, write the touch position to an UI.Text on the screen. Please add links to the other forum posts and questions.